# System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.' error in c# Decrypt Password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to compare encrypted password which is stored in mssql but when I am trying to retrieve password I am getting error System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.' Below is the Helper class

```
 namespace Fixed_Dial_DAL
 {
    public class Helper
    {
        public static string ComputeHash(string plainText,
            string hashAlgorithm, byte[] saltBytes)
        {
            // If salt is not specified, generate it.
            if (saltBytes == null)
            {
                // Define min and max salt sizes.
                int minSaltSize = 4;
                int maxSaltSize = 8;

                // Generate a random number for the size of the salt.
                Random random = new Random();
                int saltSize = random.Next(minSaltSize, maxSaltSize);

                // Allocate a byte array, which will hold the salt.
                saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];

                // Initialize a random number generator.
                RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

                // Fill the salt with cryptographically strong byte values.
                rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);
            }

            // Convert plain text into a byte array.
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

            // Allocate array, which will hold plain text and salt.
            byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes =
            new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];

            // Copy plain text bytes into resulting array.
            for (int i = 0; i < plainTextBytes.Length; i++)
                plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainTextBytes[i];

            // Append salt bytes to the resulting array.
            for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
                plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainTextBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];

            HashAlgorithm hash;

            // Make sure hashing algorithm name is specified.
            if (hashAlgorithm == null)
                hashAlgorithm = "";

            // Initialize appropriate hashing algorithm class.
            switch (hashAlgorithm.ToUpper())
            {

                case "SHA384":
                    hash = new SHA384Managed();
                    break;

                case "SHA512":
                    hash = new SHA512Managed();
                    break;

                default:
                    hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                    break;
            }

            // Compute hash value of our plain text with appended salt.
            byte[] hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);

            // Create array which will hold hash and original salt bytes.
            byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = new byte[hashBytes.Length +
            saltBytes.Length];

            // Copy hash bytes into resulting array.
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
                hashWithSaltBytes[i] = hashBytes[i];

            // Append salt bytes to the result.
            for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
                hashWithSaltBytes[hashBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];

            // Convert result into a base64-encoded string.
            string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashWithSaltBytes);

            // Return the result.
            return hashValue;
        }

        public static bool VerifyHash(string plainText, string hashAlgorithm, string hashValue)
        {

            // Convert base64-encoded hash value into a byte array.
            byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);

            // We must know size of hash (without salt).
            int hashSizeInBits, hashSizeInBytes;

            // Make sure that hashing algorithm name is specified.
            if (hashAlgorithm == null)
                hashAlgorithm = "";

            // Size of hash is based on the specified algorithm.
            switch (hashAlgorithm.ToUpper())
            {

                case "SHA384":
                    hashSizeInBits = 384;
                    break;

                case "SHA512":
                    hashSizeInBits = 512;
                    break;

                default: // Must be MD5
                    hashSizeInBits = 128;
                    break;
            }

            // Convert size of hash from bits to bytes.
            hashSizeInBytes = hashSizeInBits / 8;

            // Make sure that the specified hash value is long enough.
            if (hashWithSaltBytes.Length < hashSizeInBytes)
                return false;

            // Allocate array to hold original salt bytes retrieved from hash.
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[hashWithSaltBytes.Length - hashSizeInBytes];

            // Copy salt from the end of the hash to the new array.
            for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
                saltBytes[i] = hashWithSaltBytes[hashSizeInBytes + i];

            // Compute a new hash string.
            string expectedHashString = ComputeHash(plainText, hashAlgorithm, saltBytes);

            // If the computed hash matches the specified hash,
            // the plain text value must be correct.
            return (hashValue == expectedHashString);
        }

    }
 }



     using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    using (DataSet dataSet = new DataSet())
                  {

                        con.Open();

                        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aMail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = aMail;
                        //sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = aPassword;

                        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
                        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

                        con.Close();


                        string adminPassword = dataTable.Rows[0].Field<string>("aPassword");

                        bool flag = Helper.VerifyHash(aPassword, "SHA512", adminPassword);

                        //    bool loginSuccessful = ((dataSet.Tables.Count > 0) && (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0));



                        return flag;
```

Here is how i am trying to decrypting password which is encrypted with this:

```
string ePass = Helper.ComputeHash(aPassword, "SHA512", null);
```

But when i am trying to decrypt this password and authenticating user login  i am getting error which is said in subject.getting error on the following:

```
byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);
```

Comment: This code *hashes* the password and then validates it. It doesn't encrypt or decrypt anything.

Comment: _"i am getting error which is said in subject"_ at which line exactly?

Comment: Have you debugged this and verified that actually have a Base64 string there?

Comment: byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue); at this line i am getting error System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Comment: ASP.NET, any stack (Web Forms, MVC, Core) already hashes passwords securely. All hashes allow you to specify the algorithm to use and hash the password *multiple* times eg 1000+. They can also be configured to target custom databases or tables. There's no reason to write your own code.

Comment: @Jitender that error is clear. That string isn't a proper Base64 string. Wherever that string was stored, it's no longer a valid BASE64 string. Perhaps it was truncated? In any case, a hash is a binary value anyway, you don't need to store it as a string

Comment: @Jitender why are you trying to write your own authentication code at all? What you do is already available out-of-the-box

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos guide me sir how i can store encryted password in database and decript it later on at login time

Comment: At a quick glance it looks to me like the problem might be that you're creating a salt of random length, which is not stored separately anywhere (so you cannot easily separate it / get it back later), and additionaly it looks like you're appending the salt twice, first before hasing and then after hashing too... Have you tried storing the salt separately, and only append it to the plain text before hashing?

Comment: @Jitender passwords are stored *hashed*, not encrypted.

Comment: static string Encrypt(string value) // Encryption of Password
        {
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] data = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(value));
                return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
            }
        }

Comment: I got above code for encrypting password but how to decript that?

Comment: @Jitender you should **never encrypt** passwords. Instead you should **always hash** them. You see? _"encrypt to store -> decrypt to check"_ is **no-no-no**, _"hash to store -> compare hashes to check"_ is ok. There is no good, obvious and secure use-case for decrypting users password.